# Synch Two Calendars?

Tags: ruby

I'm brand new to learning Ruby. I learned eons ago some basic Pascal in high school - but this is of course comparing apples to oranges. What I do have is a partner who is much more experienced than I in the language.

I am attempting to create a program that can compare two different calendar styles to each other. Obviously the Gregorian calendar that we use on a daily basis and a Kemetic (Ancient Egyptian) calendar. The Kemetic calendar consists of 3 seasons with four months each and 30 days to each month. The first four months are Akhet, the second four are Peret, the final four are Shomu. Additionally there is a micro-month (Intercalary) that consists of 5 days, 6 during a leap year. A new Kemetic year starts on Aug 5th, or Aug 6th during a leap year.

The code is working to have the two calendars running side-by-side, however it is the part where I am trying to have them work together or translate from A-to-B where I could use some assistance. E.g. Today is 03 July 2021, what is the Kemetic date?

The first part of it is posted here, the rest at PasteBin: https://pastebin.com/uDNsbCJd

```
require 'date'
 
class KemeticDate 
    @@kem_months = ['IAkhet', 'IIAkhet', 'IIIAkhet', 'IVAkhet', 
                'IPeret', 'IIPeret', 'IIIPeret', 'IVPeret', 
                'IShomu', 'IIShomu', 'IIIShomu', 'IVShomu', 
                'Intercalary']
 
    @@jul_months = ['January', 'February', 'March',
                'April', 'May', 'June', 'July',
                'August', 'September', 'October',
                'November', 'December']
end
```

Comment: What you need is a formula for converting between Kemetic and a common standard such as Julian Day.

Comment: See for example https://planetcalc.com/8448/. But in the absence of modern pharaohs to restart the calendar it seems a bit hopeless.